# Swift 4 AlamofireImage with UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am using AlamofireImages to try to download an image from a server and display it in my table view cell, this is what I got, but my images does not appear, just the textLabel and detailTextLabel

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trendingCell", for: indexPath)

        print(self.array[indexPath.row])

        cell.textLabel?.text = (self.array[indexPath.row]["title"] as! String)

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (self.array[indexPath.row]["username"] as! String)

        Alamofire.request("http://xxxxxxx.com/uploads/" + (self.array[indexPath.row]["cover"] as! String)).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Is `cell.imageView?.image = image` called? Do you have any error logs in console? Is `cell.imageView` not nil?

Comment: Did you check if your `response` is valid or not, by providing a `print(response)` inside your completion block?

Comment: Can you verify that the image urls are valid and the requests are successful. Add some additional logging around this function, check response is valid etc

Comment: This might looks silly but try to remove corner radius , If you have set any background color set to default , remove any layer operation like shadow , try to toggle clips to bounds , I have the same issue but don't remember exact solution what i did but i did one of above

Comment: Try any static image as placeholder and check is it showing properly, or user alamofire's imageview's extension `imageView.af_setImage(` and also print `response`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Alamofire.request(imageUrl!, method: .get).response { response in
                    guard let image = UIImage(data:response.data!) else {
                        // Handle error
                        return
                    }
                    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0)
                    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(data : imageData!)
                }
```

This works fine for me..
Hope This will helpful.

Comment: Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'myImage'

Comment: 'myImage' is the outlet of the UIImageView in UItableviewcell.so here You should write the name of your IBOutlet variable name .

Comment: like,  cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data : imageData!)

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }   Add this...

Answer (score 4):

Of course your image will not show for you. Cause when Alamofire starts downloading your image its process in background thread. But you are working in Main Thread or UI Thread so you need to swap from background to Main Thread it will work for you.

```
Alamofire.request("http://xxxxxxx.com/uploads/" + (self.array[indexPath.row]["cover"] as! String)).responseImage { response in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let image = response.result.value {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            }
        }
}
```

If you think it is difficulty for you to do this i recommend you to use this library called Kingfisher it will handle asynchronous loading images for you that make your cell's table run in smoothly.

Link: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: response.result.value, what kind of this response?

Comment: Alamofire by default calls the response handler on the main dispatch queue, see [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling). So wrapping the handling in an `async` closure is not needed, unless `responseImage` acts differently than the standard `response...`es. Everything points to an invalid image or URL.

Answer (score 2):

## Using AlamofireImages

```
if let url = URL(string: "your url") {

    cell.imageView?.af_setImage(withURL:url, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil,  imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2), runImageTransitionIfCached: false, completion: {response in
      // do stuff when is downloaded completely.
    })
}
```

Comment: What result do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

Create this function first to help pull down the image. If you're pulling multiple images, you may want to create a new swift file and make this static or just call it in the file that you need it. This way you can refer to it instead of re-writing code:

```
static func loadImage(_ imageView: UIImageView,_ urlString: String) {
    let imgURL: URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imgURL) { (data, respond, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return}

        DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)  
        })
    }.resume()
}
```

Then to pull down the info:

```
if let logoName = variable.logo {
        StaticFileName.loadImage(cell.imgVariableInCell, "\(logoName)")
    }
    return cell
}
```

Then you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this code in the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    cell.imageView?.image = image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage

First You need to Import this

```
import SDWebImage
```

Then You may use this method

```
let imgUrl = URL(string:"your image URL string")
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: imgUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "propic"))
```

Comment: I get this error `Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_setImage'`

Comment: For that you have to add SDWebImage framework And import the this method will be available

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. 
i think the transport security block your image over http . 
add this into your info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>         //put your domain name here
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

and you can also use the alamofire's image library. just add pod alamofireImage.

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to check , have you got the proper response if you got the reasponse than write the code like**

```
Alamofire.request(imageUrl!, method: .get).response { response in

                           if let image = UIImage(data: response.data!) {
                          cell. imageView?.image = image
                     }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the link as a variable to a variable in the cell and override the awakefromnib function in UITableViewCell. Inside the awakeFrom nib you call the alamofire request to load the image in the cell, with this way you will not call the query every time it reuses the cell.

so

//CellCode

```
import Alamofire
...

    var imageLink:String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
    Alamofire.request(imageLink).responseImage { response in
                if let image = response.result.value {
                    self.imageView?.image = image
                }
            }
    }


//cell configuration
cell.imageLink = "http://xxxxxxx.com/uploads/" + self.array[indexPath.row]["cover"] as! String)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift-5 Supported Code That Work Perfectly**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.lblName.text = arrData[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String

  let imageUrl = arrData[indexPath.row]["imageUrl"] as? String

    Alamofire.request(imageUrl!, method: .get).response { response in
        guard let image = UIImage(data:response.data!) else {
            // Handle error
            return
        }
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        cell.imgCourses.image = UIImage(data : imageData!)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: use imageUrl as String

Comment: and alamofire request in tableview cell